# Porque este doble bucle no avanza?

Tags: java, bucles

Como dice en el titulo, este doble bucle no avanza. Este codigo es para mover los elementos de un arreglo N espacios a la derecha. Utilizando un codigo simple dentro de un bucle doble.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i,ultimo,mover,f;
    int[] numeros =new int[10];
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);

    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        numeros[i]=entrada.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.println("Cuantos espacios desea mover el arreglo?");
    mover=entrada.nextInt();
    
    for(i=0;i<mover;i++) {
        ultimo=numeros[9];
         for(f=9;f>0;i--){
            numeros[f]=numeros[f-1];
        }
        numeros[0]=ultimo;
    }
```

Comment: En el bucle interior no modificas `f`, sino `i`

Comment: En el bucle exterior sumas 1 a i en cada iteración, mientras que en el interior le restas 1 a i, por lo que i nunca será mayor de mover.

Answer (score 0):

Por que como bien dice SJuan76 hay que usar la variable correcta, sino nunca se cumple la condición para salir del bucle.

```
for(f=9;f>0;f--){
```